# How to center a facebook iframe like button

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I need a global solution to center a facebook iframe like button which can have different like urls and different locales (and languages - in my case 40+). So the button will have different widths in the end.

According to that I removed the width attribute and added the locale param. The iframe gets 300px wide and its not possible to center it.

See the problem in this example:

```css
.mydiv {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.mydiv span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.mydiv iframe {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <span>locale en_US</span>
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button_count&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=false&height=21&appId=848263035268773" height="21" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

  <span>locale de_DE</span>
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=de_DE&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button_count&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=false&height=21&appId=848263035268773" height="21" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Important here: I have to use the iframe soultion of the facebook like button, not the js sdk version.

Comment: Another solution: `iframe {margin: auto; display: block;}`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError this does not help here after my edit.

Comment: Same domain policies will prevent you from styling content in an iframe that is rendered from another server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Ok, so it is impossible?

Comment: Are you willing to consider javascript? You could explore the postMessage() method: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/postmessage/ | http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/

Comment: JS is ok for me

Answer (score 0):

```
.mydiv {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Add `text-align:center` to  your containing div.

Comment: It'll help if you use the property inspector in the browser :)

Comment: the edit makes my problem more clear. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I know why this was downvoted an unaccepted as answer?

Comment: Ok well it did work before your edit. No need to downvote for that. And you should clearly show which part of your original post was edited.